# using ransack to traverse a complex associated tag hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging, ransack

I have a model I which to search using Ransack called `Question` and it has the associated models `question_tags` through `question_taggings`:

```
has_many :question_taggings, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :question_tags, :through => :question_taggings
```

I can do a basic search using these tags with something like:

```
Question.ransack(question_tags_id_or_question_tags_parent_id_in: [447,449]).result
```

But for tags, we're are using the [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem which presents a problem of how to search a more complicated hierarchy of tags.

Specifically I'd like to be able to search parent tags and be able to return all of the tags associated with the tag and its descendants.  Which I can do using closure_tree like so (with SQL):

```
QuestionTag.find(447).self_and_descendants.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"question_tags\".* FROM \"question_tags\" INNER JOIN \"question_tag_hierarchies\" ON \"question_tags\".\"id\" = \"question_tag_hierarchies\".\"descendant_id\" WHERE \"question_tag_hierarchies\".\"ancestor_id\" = 447  ORDER BY \"question_tag_hierarchies\".generations asc"
```

Eg tag 447 is `sports` and it has the following self_and_descendants:

```
+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| id  | name              | created_at                | updated_at                | parent_id |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 447 | sports            | 2014-10-24 15:58:15 +0100 | 2015-01-12 15:10:12 +0000 |           |
| 462 | hockey            | 2014-10-24 18:21:18 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:21:18 +0100 | 447       |
| 464 | basketball        | 2014-10-24 18:21:31 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:21:31 +0100 | 447       |
| 465 | olympics          | 2014-10-24 18:21:40 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:21:40 +0100 | 447       |
| 466 | world cup         | 2014-10-24 18:21:56 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:21:56 +0100 | 447       |
| 467 | martial arts      | 2014-10-24 18:22:20 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:22:20 +0100 | 447       |
| 541 | american football | 2014-11-19 06:20:16 +0000 | 2014-11-19 06:20:16 +0000 | 447       |
| 542 | baseball          | 2014-11-19 06:20:23 +0000 | 2014-11-19 06:20:23 +0000 | 447       |
| 506 | cricket           | 2014-11-06 06:49:05 +0000 | 2014-11-06 06:49:05 +0000 | 447       |
| 661 | winter sports     | 2015-02-13 10:46:30 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:46:30 +0000 | 447       |
| 659 | surfing           | 2015-02-13 10:44:05 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:44:05 +0000 | 447       |
| 660 | horse racing      | 2015-02-13 10:46:07 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:46:07 +0000 | 447       |
| 461 | soccer            | 2014-10-24 18:21:12 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:21:12 +0100 | 447       |
| 463 | football          | 2014-10-24 18:21:25 +0100 | 2015-02-13 10:51:28 +0000 | 447       |
| 570 | golf              | 2015-01-15 17:22:35 +0000 | 2015-01-15 17:22:35 +0000 | 447       |
| 561 | tennis            | 2015-01-15 04:23:41 +0000 | 2015-01-15 04:23:41 +0000 | 447       |
| 601 | motor racing      | 2015-02-05 16:29:11 +0000 | 2015-02-05 16:29:11 +0000 | 447       |
| 605 | rugby             | 2015-02-05 16:30:32 +0000 | 2015-02-05 16:30:32 +0000 | 447       |
| 621 | snooker           | 2015-02-06 14:27:35 +0000 | 2015-02-06 14:27:35 +0000 | 447       |
| 655 | extreme sport     | 2015-02-13 10:38:04 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:38:04 +0000 | 447       |
| 656 | sports equipment  | 2015-02-13 10:41:42 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:41:46 +0000 | 447       |
| 657 | athletics         | 2015-02-13 10:42:26 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:42:32 +0000 | 447       |
| 658 | ballgames         | 2015-02-13 10:42:58 +0000 | 2015-02-13 10:42:58 +0000 | 447       |
| 468 | boxing            | 2014-10-24 18:22:24 +0100 | 2014-10-24 18:22:24 +0100 | 467       |
| 602 | f1                | 2015-02-05 16:29:16 +0000 | 2015-02-05 16:29:16 +0000 | 601       |
| 603 | motorbikes        | 2015-02-05 16:29:24 +0000 | 2015-02-05 16:29:24 +0000 | 601       |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

My question is how could I integrate this search using Ransack?  First off, would I create a [custom ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers)?  The problem is they don't give any complicated examples or even examples which use associated models. ;-(

Any advice would be great!  Thanks,

Comment: [RailsCast 370](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) has some great examples of complex search forms for association models.

Comment: Would you give an example of what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to split into two queries?

```
tag_ids = QuestionTag
            .where(id: [447, 499])
            .map{ |t| t.self_and_descendants }
            .uniq
            .map(&:id)

Question.ransack(question_tags_id_in: tag_ids).result
```